# How to auto generate an Aerospike primary key?

Tags: java, database, aerospike

I have a class Student

```
class Student{
   @Id
   private int id;
}
```

I want to have autogenerated Id for my key id when I am saving this into Aerospike using Spring Data Aerospike.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to it's performant and distributed nature, Aerospike doesn't have an equivalent of an `AUTO_INCREMENT` integer primary keys which are common in relational databases.

If your data doesn't have a natural primary key, then a common approach is that your app should [generate GUIDs as the key](https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/put-without-needing-to-define-the-key-auto-generate-unique-key/503) for your data. If you are still worried about collisions, then you can apply a [Write Policy with `CREATE_ONLY` of true](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/policy/RecordExistsAction.html) which will cause a write to fail if there is a collision, which will allow you to regenerate a new GUID and retry.

Comment: Note, you will need the globally unique ID to retrieve / read / update the record in the future. While CREATE_ONLY is a good write policy to ensure you are not overwriting an existing key, you have to somehow keep track of your keys. Eventually you don't just want to store, you may want to read or update specific records too.