# How to use aerospike to generate a unique auto-incrementing ID，like redis

Tags: aerospike

How to use aerospike to generate a unique auto-incrementing ID，like redis

i want to use aerospike to generate a unique auto-incrementing ID,like redis 。I don't know how I can do it，Has anyone tried this?
For example: If I am saving some Person data in DB, Do I need to create a uid for the Person or it is auto generated by the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aerospike doesn't support auto-incrementing ID due to its distributed nature.

Check out the following threads that describes it with more details.
Alternative suggestion might be to use a generated unique id as a primary key:

1. https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/auto-generate-an-id-for-a-particular-data-in-aerospike/5168
2. [How to auto generate an Aerospike primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50285742/how-to-auto-generate-an-aerospike-primary-key)

Answer (score 2):

Check out using ULIDs perhaps, these can be generated client side and there are libraries for many programming languages.

Quoting from their spec:

- 128-bit compatibility with UUID
- 1.21e+24 unique ULIDs per millisecond
- Lexicographically sortable!
- Canonically encoded as a 26 character string, as opposed to the 36 character UUID
- Uses Crockford's base32 for better efficiency and readability (5 bits per character)
- Case insensitive
- No special characters (URL safe)
- Monotonic sort order (correctly detects and handles the same millisecond)

We use these for client side ID generation in the Redis OM libraries.

https://github.com/ulid/spec